# Number of multiples of m among integer interval $[\![ 1,n ]\!]$

Tags: integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Can you show me how to solve this question?

For positive integers $m$ and $n$,show that the number of multiples of $m$ among $1, 2,...,n$ is $$ \lfloor n / m \rfloor $$
More generally, for an integer $m$ and real $x \geq 0$, show that the number of multiples of $m$ in the interval $[1, x]$ is $$ \lfloor x/m \rfloor$$

---

I started with $$ 1 \le km \le n $$ $$ 1/m \le k \le n/m $$ but I couldn't go even one more step.

Comment: The multiples of $m$ has the form $km$

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote @belkacemabderrahmane

Comment: divide sides of the inequality by $m$

Comment: The inequality $1/m \leq k$ is automatically satisfied, because $k$ and $m$ are positive integers. So you only need to work out how many positive integers $k$ there are that satisfy the second inequality. The argument is just the same with $x$ in place of $n,$ so you may as well do it all in one go. You're already very nearly there - so you may be able to write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the unique integer such that $a\le x<a+1$.

Then $\lfloor\frac{a}{m}\rfloor \le \lfloor\frac{x}{m}\rfloor < \lfloor\frac{a+1}{m}\rfloor$.

Therefore $\lfloor\frac{x}{m}\rfloor =\lfloor\frac{a}{m}\rfloor$.